# multmap equal_range in C++

Tags: c++, multimap

This example for use of `equal_range` is offered on the cplusplus.com site:

```
 int main ()
 {
   std::multimap<char,int> mymm;

   mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('a',10));
   mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',20));
   mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',30));
   mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',40));
   mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('c',50));
   mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('c',60));
   mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('d',60));

   std::cout << "mymm contains:\n";
   for (char ch='a'; ch<='d'; ch++)
   {
      std::pair <std::multimap<char,int>::iterator, std::multimap<char,int>::iterator> ret;
      ret = mymm.equal_range(ch);
      std::cout << ch << " =>";
      for (std::multimap<char,int>::iterator it=ret.first; it!=ret.second; ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << it->second;
      std::cout << '\n';
   }
```

And the output is said to be:

```
mymm contains:
a => 10
b => 20 30 40
c => 50 60
d => 60
```

But isn't this wrong? For 'd' for instance the condition `it!=ret.second` will immediately fail and the loop will never be executed? Or have I got this wrong? (This matters as I have based some code on this example and on a second look think it's likely to misbehave.)

Comment: Iterator intervals are half-open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second iterator in the range is "one-past-the-end" of where it would be just like the way `mymm.end()` works. If `mymm.begin()` and `mymm.end()` are the same there is nothing in the container. Here, `ret.first` and `ret.second` being the same, means there is no element in the resulting range. Since there is one element for 'd', `ret.first` points to that element and `ret.second` is the same as `mymm.end()`.

Comment: cheers. Sadly that rules out one reason why my code was misbehaving :(

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not wrong. According to

> Returns a range containing all elements with the given key in the
>   container. The range is defined by two iterators, one pointing to the
>   first element that is not less than key and another pointing to the
>   first element greater than key.

from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range it works as expected.